# Can not decrypt data which was encrypted using SecureRandom

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I was using this code segment to encrypt my image data 2 years ago. At that time my target SDK was 22. But When i try to update my SDK i face that i can not decrypt it. I find out that Android deprecated this encryption method. Is there any way to solve this problem so that i can decrypt  my images. 
Thanks in advance.

```
public byte[] EncryptByte(byte[] rawInputByte){        

    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    try {
        byte[] yourKey = generateKey("password");
        fileBytes = encodeFile(yourKey, rawInputByte);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }

    return fileBytes;
}

public byte[] generateKey(String password) throws Exception
{
    byte[] keyStart = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
    sr.setSeed(keyStart);
    kgen.init(128, sr);
    SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
    return skey.getEncoded();
}
```

Comment: [Read this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/06/security-crypto-provider-deprecated-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

At last i can solve this. Thanks James K Polk for giving me the link. My code segment is given below and InsecureSHA1PRNGKeyDerivator link is [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BrokenKeyDerivation/src/com/example/android/brokenkeyderivation/InsecureSHA1PRNGKeyDerivator.java). Hope it will help you guys.

```
public byte[] decodeFile(byte[] fileData) throws Exception
{     
    SecretKey insecureKey = deriveKeyInsecurely("password", 16);
    byte[] decryptedData = decryptData(fileData, insecureKey);

    return decryptedData;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
private static SecretKey deriveKeyInsecurely(String password, int
        keySizeInBytes) throws Exception {
    byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    return new SecretKeySpec( InsecureSHA1PRNGKeyDerivator.deriveInsecureKey(  passwordBytes, keySizeInBytes),  "AES");
}


private static byte[] decryptData(
        byte[] data, SecretKey key) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key );

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This is unconceivable!", e);
    }
}
```